# How to prevent java.net.UnknownHostException using org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping

Tags: java, snmp4j

How do I avoid the UnknownHostException in this line:

```
TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
```

I use the SNMP4J 2.2.0 API and use multiple threads (one thread for each switch)

Comment: Use a hostname that does exist?

Comment: As this is obviously an SNMP4J issue, remove the general SNMP tag.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got this fixed by calling

```
TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
```

only once for each thread. With 50 threads it still works fine.

My guess is that the networkIf / OS / Java was out of available ports